# ffmpeg conversion for apple tv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have one particular movie file that is giving me grief while I am trying to convert my movie library to be able to be viewed on my Apple TV. I have been using iFlicks to convert all of my files and have only had one issue. The original of this particular movie file plays fine but after it has been converted the video freezes after a few minutes but the audio keeps playing. I tried using ffmpeg to convert the file but now the file is very choppy. The first time it is played the video will be choppy, the next time the audio will be choppy... but it plays fine in VLC for some reason. So I was thinking that maybe I have chosen the wrong codecs to suit Quicktime/Apple TV. Below is the command I used for ffmpeg. Have I chosen the right codecs and actually written the command correctly? (I haven't really used ffmpeg before...)

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac output.m4v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem by setting the frame rate value to an integer (eg 24 instead of the original 23.976)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec libx264 -r 24 -acodec libfaac output.m4v`

Comment: that worked perfectly. although its odd how this affected only one or two files from my fairly large library. Any ideas on why this happened?

Comment: Actually all of the others (in the same TV series) decimal have frame rates (about 23.97) before and after conversion and work fine. And the troublesome file did work fine in VLC when it didn't in Quicktime. I know this shouldn't bother me because I now have a solution but I like to learn as much as I can about these things so I can avoid issues in the future...

Comment: I have found a few more of my files that have had the same issue but there is nothing that differentiates them from the ones that actually work. Any ideas on what to look for in the future?